# Show image in a popup when I click button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button and i need to show an image in a popup when i click this button.

Why this code doesn't work? I try with a window.open in `onclick` event but it doesn't work

```
<input type="button" value="Mostra Immagine" onclick=window.open(src="../img/mypicture.jpg")>
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **[fancybox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox)** to do it.

```css
a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.primary-btn {
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, #235ee7 0%, #4ae7fa 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, #235ee7 0%, #4ae7fa 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, #235ee7 0%, #4ae7fa 100%);
}

.primary-btn {
  line-height: 36px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
}

.primary-btn {
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.primary-btn:hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #235ee7;
  border-color: #235ee7;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.0/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.0/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.2.0/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
<a data-fancybox="gallery" class="primary-btn" href="//source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/300x300">Demo</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the `"` in onclick  and add with `_blank` for new page .passing the argument with in function using `'` quotes

```
<input type="button" value="Mostra Immagine" onclick="window.open('../img/mypicture.jpg','_blank')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the attribute and function wrong:

```
onclick="window.open('../img/mypicture.jpg');"
```

Always quote an attribute value like you did for `type` and `value`.
And the `window.open` function needs a path, you don't need to write "src=".
[MDN - window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Popup text...</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Popup container */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
// When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>
```

You can read more here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_popup.asp
Hope Helpful

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16351375)

Comment: @Badacadabra : Thank you for your comments .I edited my answer.